# Can one edit a built-in Python module?

Tags: python, libraries, math, modules

I'm currently learning Python and I'm at the point in the book about using the Math library. I looked on the Python website and noticed the library was a bit scarce and am writing some more useful functions. For example, I went ahead and wrote a function to take coefficients and return the roots of the equation. Essentially a quadratic formula function. I'm wondering if it's possible to add this to the python Math library. If it isn't, how do I save it such that I can use that function in other Python programs I write just by calling it?

Comment: There is an [answer below](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/159046/1860) by Michael0x2a that covers the fine points, but the simple version is: don't do that. If I am reading your code and see a call to `math.polynomial_roots()` me and my interpreter will become confused. That's a Bad Thing.

Answer (score 11):

The math module is a [builtin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7803235/python-module-location), so short of modifying the Python interpreter itself, I don't think you can modify it.  However, writing a module is definitely something you can do.

If you structure your files like this:

```
somefolder
    mymath.py
    myprogram.py
```

...you could simply do `import mymath` inside `myprogram.py`, and use any functions or classes inside `mymath.py` as normal.

So if `mymath.py` looks like this:

```
def quadratic(a, b, c):
    # blah blah blah
```

You could do the below inside `myprogram.py`

```
import mymath

print mymath.quadratic(1, 2, 3)
```

If you want the module you've written available for any program, you could either copy-and-paste it into the folder of any project you're working on, or add it to your PATH.  (For example, you could include `mymath.py` inside the site-packages folder, which is located at `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` on my computer).  Once you do that, you should be able to do `import mymath` without ever having to copy-and-paste anything.

As a side-note, [numpy](https://numpy.org/) has a pretty comprehensive set of math and science related functions that you could check out.  It's pretty much the de-facto standard for numerical computation in Python, afaik.

Comment: Exactly the answer I would've written. Python is designed to be modded, quite literally.